# Trying to add a plugin to CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor, apostrophe-cms

I'm trying to add a plugin to set a default URL when adding a link.

I followed the instructions here:
https://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/howtos/ckeditor.html

And I ended up with:

```
// lib/modules/apostrophe-areas/public/js/user.js
apos.define('apostrophe-areas', {
    construct: function(self, options) {

    var superEnableCkeditor = self.enableCkeditor;

    self.enableCkeditor = function() {
    superEnableCkeditor();

    CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal('defaulturl', '/modules/my-apostrophe-areas/js/ckeditorPlugins/defaulturl/', 'plugin.js');
  };
 }
});
```

and this is my apostrophe-areas/public/js/ckeditorPlugins/defaulturl/plugin.js

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'dialogDefinition', function( ev ) {

    var dialogName = ev.data.name;
    var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;

    if ( dialogName == 'link' ) {

        var infoTab = dialogDefinition.getContents( 'info' );
        var urlField = infoTab.get( 'url' );

        urlField[ 'default' ] = 'www.example.com';
    }
});
```

However, this is not working for me, I tried to do what is suggested here:
[Ckeditor plugin configuration not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45427718/ckeditor-plugin-configuration-not-working/45534336)

But it doesn't worked.

What I've tried and worked was to append the plugin.js file at the end of the plugin.js of the split plugin at the apostrophe-area folder, but I think this is not the correct way to go

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can solve the issue two ways:

## 1. If you want to keep the external plugin file:

Wrap your code according to the API, see e.g. https://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/timestamp.html and the plugin it references https://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/assets/plugins/timestamp/plugin.js for an example. You need to use `CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'defaulturl', { init: ... })` in your plugin.js. Not sure if there is anything special to do otherwise as you want to modify the behavior of a CKEDITOR core plugin. That's why it would go with the next option...

## 2. If you don't need the extra `plugin.js`:

You can also replace the `CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal()` call with the contents of your `plugin.js` file. I did this to modify the default link target to be `_blank`:

```js
// /lib/modules/apostrophe-areas/public/js/user.js
'use strict';

// See https://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/howtos/ckeditor.html and
apos.define('apostrophe-areas', {
  construct: function(self, options) {
    var superEnableCkeditor = self.enableCkeditor;

    self.enableCkeditor = function enableCkeditor() {
      superEnableCkeditor();

      // https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_howtos_dialog_windows.html
      CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function redefineDialog(ev) {
        var dialogName = ev.data.name;
        var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;

        if (dialogName === 'link') {
          var targetTab = dialogDefinition.getContents('target');
          var targetField = targetTab.get('linkTargetType');

          targetField.default = '_blank';
        }
      });
    };
  }
});
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much! I could solve it with the 2nd way, I think I got a little mixed up since I'm new to CKEditor